# eeepc 1018pb dual display wrong resolution size

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, eeepc

My Setup:

- eeepc 1018pb with Intel GMA 3150.
- Ubuntu 11.10 x64_86
- Samsung SyncMaster 2333

The Problem:

I connect the Samsung with the eeepc. Ubuntu recognizes the Display.
When I try to activate it and set the native resolution (1920x1080), I get the following Error:

> The selected configuration for display could not be applied Requested size(2944, 1080) exceeds 3D hardware limit (2048, 2048)...

Note that the width is exactly 1024px larger than I selected. This offset is kept for any resolution I choose.

If I choose a resolution with a width smaller than 1024 it applies exactly the selected resolution. So I guess the error occurs only during the "error checking". Which is a little bit funny.

So basically I have no idea how to fix this. I searched for two days know without any usable result.

I looked for new drivers, but I couldn't find anything besides http://intellinuxgraphics.org. But as I understood this drivers are already used by Ubuntu natively. Besides I have no idea how to install them by hand.

- jockey-gtk doesn't even suggest graphic drivers.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you will not be able to fix this, at least not with Unity 3D (I guess you use this). The reason: when using two screens, the screens are represented as one big screen. No matter whether the two small screens are merged side by side or over each other, you exceed the maximum resolution of the graphics hardware.

Solutions are: live without 3D support, means try Unity 2D or another desktop manager without 3D hardware acceleration.

or

Choose a resolution (of the internal or external screen) where either the sum of the horizontal or the sum of the vertical pixles is <= 2048

Comment: I had no idea about this representation. This explains my troubles. Thanks a lot. The solution I'm using know is simply position one screen beneath the other. So in my case this would be 1920x1680.

Comment: glad to help you. I did not know the resolution of the internal screen but if it is less than 2048-1080 this solution works ;) However, you have to move the mouse down (or up) to reach the other screen while it might be located right of the primary screen. This might be annoying. However, please mark the answer as okay, thus your question will be marked as solved.